# How does bundler handle multiple 'bundle install' commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation, bundle, gemfile

Say I have two different Rails apps with different gem versions specified in their respective Gemfiles. The first app's Gemfile specifies the latest versions of each gem. The second app's Gemfile specifies older versions of each gem.

If I run `bundle install` from the root of the first app's directory, and then run `bundle install` from the root of the second app's directory. Will all the gems on my local machine be reverted to an older state?

The reason I ask is that I want to clone an older rail app's repository from GitHub, run it on my local machine, and play around with it. Thanks!

Comment: Bundler places each version of a gem in its own folder so you can potentially have gems which have dependencies on different versions of another gem as long as the overall dependency graph can be resolved. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvFfd_MCJq0

Comment: yay I got the app running! Thanks for the clarification on how bundler manages gems, one less thing to worry about.